# Vapor with Postgres - table is not getting prepared

Tags: swift, postgresql, vapor

I have 3 `Model` objects in my project.

```
drop.preparations.append(Club.self)
drop.preparations.append(ClubPlayers.self)
drop.preparations.append(Player.self)
```

for some reason, Club table is not created. this is my `prepare` method:

```
static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.create(Club.tableName, closure: { club in
            club.id()
            club.string(Club.nameColumn)
            club.string(Club.urlColumn)
        })

}
```

it's built exactly as my other models, but it's the only one that is not being created. I don't receive any warning or error.
I'm using Swift 3.1.1, vapor 1.5 and vapor-toolbox 2

Comment: You need to use the proper toolbox with your Vapor version. With Vapor 1.x, use Toolbox 1.x (`brew install vapor1`). If you have Vapor 2.x, use Toolbox 2.x (`brew install vapor`).

Comment: Try doing `vapor run prepare --revert --all` then running your app again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was: remove the 'Club' row from the 'fluent' table. then running `vapor run prepare` did work.
There are also other options:

- use migration. https://vapor.github.io/documentation/fluent/model.html#preparations-as-migrations
- use psql `ADD COLUMN` command. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-add-column/
- I didn't try [tanner0101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041105/tanner0101) suggestion, but it sounds interesting